# Outer join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have written a code for outer join in Oracle. Its giving me 'missing keyword' error

```
create table Fenergo_data_01 as select tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
from  Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 full outer join  Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2
full outer join  Fenergo_address_data tab3
full outer join Fenergo_MCH_data tab4
on tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID and tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID 
and tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the join condition for each `join` (in the `on` clause), not once at the end like you did:

```
CREATE TABLE     Fenergo_data_01 AS
SELECT           tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
FROM             Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 
FULL OUTER JOIN  Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2 ON tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN  Fenergo_address_data tab3 ON tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID 
FULL OUTER JOIN Fenergo_MCH_data tab4 ON tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```

Answer (score 1):

The on clause must be included as part of the join statement.

```
create table Fenergo_data_01 as 
select tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
from  Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 
full outer join Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID
full outer join Fenergo_address_data tab3 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID
full outer join Fenergo_MCH_data tab4 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `on` clause must follow the join:

```
create table Fenergo_data_01 as select tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
from  Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 full outer join  Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID 
full outer join  Fenergo_address_data tab3 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID 
full outer join Fenergo_MCH_data tab4 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/join.html) page for more information about the `join` syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `ON` after every join, like this:

```
create table Fenergo_data_01 as 
select tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
 from  Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 
 full outer join  Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID
 full outer join  Fenergo_address_data tab3 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID
 full outer join Fenergo_MCH_data tab4 on tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid join would be as below (Join followed by on condition)

```
SELECT * FROM TABA 
     JOIN TABB 
         ON TABA_SOMEID = TABB_SOMEID
```

Try below query:

```
create table Fenergo_data_01 as 
select tab1.* , tab2.* , tab3.*, tab4.*
from  
    Fenergo_ext_ref_data tab1 
    full outer join  
    Fenergo_cntry_incorp_data tab2
         on tab1.FGO_ID = tab2.FGO_ID
         full outer join  
         Fenergo_address_data tab3
                on tab1.FGO_ID = tab3.FGO_ID 
                full outer join 
                Fenergo_MCH_data tab4
                      on tab1.FGO_ID = tab4.FGO;
```